# Linux replace a "//" string to "/"

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I need to replace a string "//" to the string "/". For example:

```
/video//5//record
```

I need it to be:

```
/video/5/record
```

I want to use sed:

```
sed -i -e 's//////g' inputfile
```

But I think I have some problem deal with the escape char.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3):

sed can use other delimiters ( any punctuation character )
Try:

```
     sed -i -e 's://:/:g' infile
```

Comment: Can't imagine why this got downvoted - have an upvote for the right answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the below by escaping.

```
$ echo "/video//5//record" | sed -e 's/\/\//\//g'
/video/5/record
```